# Jquery code that got broken after upgrading to 1.7.1 from 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that works just fine in 1.3.2 and is broken in 1.7.1 can anybody point me to what if not correct with the code:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({ 
    autoscroll: function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css({overflow:'hidden'});
            if(options == 'horizontal') $this.mousemove(function(e) {
                var width = $this.width();
                $this.attr({ scrollLeft: ($this.attr('scrollWidth')-width)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageX-$this.offset().left)/width)/2) });
            });
            else if(options == 'vertical') $this.mousemove(function(e) {
                var height = $this.height();
                $this.attr({ scrollTop: ($this.attr('scrollHeight')-height)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageY-$this.offset().top)/height)/2) });
            });
            else if(options == 'both') $this.mousemove(function(e) {
                var width = $this.width(), height = $this.height();
                $this.attr({ scrollLeft: ($this.attr('scrollWidth')-width)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageX-$this.offset().left)/width)/2), scrollTop: ($this.attr('scrollHeight')-height)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageY-$this.offset().top)/height)/2) });
            });
            else $this.mousemove(function(e) {
                var width = $this.width(), height = $this.height();
                $this.attr({ scrollLeft: ($this.attr('scrollWidth')-width)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageX-$this.offset().left)/width)/2), scrollTop: ($this.attr('scrollHeight')-height)*(0.5-Math.cos(Math.PI*(e.pageY-$this.offset().top)/height)/2) });
            });
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Why not follow standard js conventions? You're code would be much easier to debug if you properly enclose your `if else` statements in curly braces `{}`

Comment: There has been a plethora of changes in between those two versions. Trying to upgrade is likely just asking for rewriting large parts of it. Try to keep up with upgrades in the future and prevent problems you can't solve yourself. Missing brackets don't help either.

Comment: @elclanrs Which standard are you referring to? I don't find this hard to read at all.

Comment: The behaviour of `attr()` changed in 1.6, so check if `prop()` works for you.

Comment: **@James McLaughlin** I'm talking about the Crokford coding conventions, jslint, etc...

Comment: @j08691 i get no error it just does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attr()` only for HTML-attributes. For JS/DOM-properties (e.g. scrollWidth, scrollTop) use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

`prop()` has been introduced in v1.6.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uKMWQ/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uKMWQ/)

Comment: This is something I've wondered about. Do you have any documentation or further reading?

Comment: While useful, linking to the jQuery docs is not what I meant.

Comment: What do you mean? The difference between a (DOM)-property and a (HTML)-attribute?

Comment: It's not always so simple. A comprehensive explanation of each special case (like disabled) as it's affected would be nice, but a value-add.

Comment: All attributes are properties but not all properties are attributes.  In other words, attributes are a sub-set of properties.  So to keep it simple, just use `prop()` for both.

Comment: It's not that easy, as Jared said. e.g. 'checked' or 'href' will return different values depending on the way you access them (as property or as attribute)

Comment: @Sparky672 - I have tiried with prop() and get the same effect.

Comment: @lstanczyk, I just made a general comment... I was not telling you how to fix your code.

Comment: @lstanczyk: I was just taking the code above, replaced all occurencies of "attr" with "prop" and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/uKMWQ/

Comment: @Dr.Molle you are right - a little bit of fiddler and i realized my webserver kept sending cached old version of the JS. Thank you for your help!